# bad_weak_ptr when using enable_shared_from_this

Tags: c++, c++17, std

I have a base class

```
class eventreceiver {
public:
  eventreceiver() = default;
  virtual ~eventreceiver() = default;

  virtual void on_quit();
}
```

And I have a class which uses it

```
class engine : public eventreceiver, std::enable_shared_from_this<engine> {
public:
  virtual ~engine() = default;

  [[nodiscard]] static std::shared_ptr<engine> create();

  void init(std::string_view title, int32_t width, int32_t height, bool fullscreen = false);

  void add_loopable(std::shared_ptr<loopable> loopable);

  void run();

protected:
  virtual void on_quit() override;

private:
  engine() = default;

  bool _running;

  std::list<std::shared_ptr<loopable>> _loopables;
  std::shared_ptr<window> _window;
  std::shared_ptr<renderer> _renderer;
  std::shared_ptr<eventmanager> _eventmanager;
};
```

When I try to pass the shared_ptr from `shared_from_this` below

```
void engine::init(std::string_view title, int32_t width, int32_t height, bool fullscreen) {
  _running = true;
  _window = std::make_shared<window>(title, width, height, fullscreen);
  _renderer = _window->create_renderer();
  _eventmanager = std::make_shared<eventmanager>();

  _eventmanager->add_receiver(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<eventreceiver>(shared_from_this())); // HERE

  add_loopable(std::make_shared<framerate>());
}
```

I receive the exception `bad_weak_ptr`.

What I am doing wrong and how can I pass the shared_ptr of "engine" to "_eventmanager"?

EDIT: minimal reproducible example -> https://onlinegdb.com/4VTq1mMnc

Comment: A [mcve] would be most helpful, because then we could run your code and see the problem.  I would use a debugger.  But, alas, this code does not compile — it is incomplete.  I cannot copy-and-paste it into `a.cpp` and compile it, and run it.  For starters, it is missing `#include <memory>`.  I could fill in the blanks, but I suspect there is good chance if I do so I won't recreate the bug.

Comment: 1. Don't do `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`, you don't need anything in particular to upcast (and it may be dangerous if you ever need to change it and forget about the cast). 2. Was the instance of `engine` in question managed with `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: @Eljay here is the MRE https://onlinegdb.com/4VTq1mMnc

Comment: @Yksisarvinen without DPC I cannot pass to the function, since it expects a `std::shared_ptr<eventreceiver>`

Comment: @Rodrigo Yes, you can: https://godbolt.org/z/jsvcrxq5W. Smart pointers to derived class are implicitly convertible to smart pointer to base class (just like regular pointers are).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen what you have changed? Because in my MRE I have the crash, and yours no.

Comment: @Rodrigo That example was not executed, only compiled. I wanted to show that no `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` is needed :) If you executed it, it would also throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can only use `shared_from_this` with an object that already is shared.

You need

```
auto e = std::make_shared<engine>();
e->init();
```

Second, it is very easy to forget that explicit access protection on inheritance must be applied to each base class individually.

This,

```
public eventreceiver, std::enable_shared_from_this<engine>
```

inherits *privately* from `std::enable_shared_from_this<engine>`, which makes the machine go BOOM.

You need

```
public eventreceiver, public std::enable_shared_from_this<engine>
```

And you don't need to mess around with casting.

Answer (score 4):

[`shared_from_this()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this) can *only* be called if `this` is managed by `shared_ptr`.

This will not work:

```
engine e;
e.init();
```

This will work:

```
std::shared_ptr<engine> e = engine::create();
e->init();
```

---

On an unrelated note, you should avoid `dynamic_cast` and it's smart pointer counter part `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`. In particular, no cast is needed here: `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` is implicitly convertible to `std::shared_ptr<Base>` (just like `Derived*` is implicitly convertible to `Base*`).

Comment: If I execute the code that you shared on godbolt, it also give me a bad weak ptr. And also I applied your suggestion and still have bad weak ptr.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have shared pointer to something what is created on stack!
You have constructed `engine` in invalid way. Anything what inherits from `std::enable_shared_from_this` should be allocated on heap.

Best method is std:make_shared:

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto e = std::make_shared<engine>();
    e->init();

    return 0;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/bdjs67P5Y

Note also you have forgotten `public` keyword before `std::enable_shared_from_this<engine>`! Without this `shared_from_this` won't work.